# I have used $function in my mongoose aggregation query. Can we use moment inside that $function?

Tags: mongodb, function, mongoose, mongodb-query, moment-timezone

I have written mongoose aggregation query where I am using $function inside that with $add field.In that function I am converting out some dates, for that I have used moment library. But it throws me an error inside that $function like mongoose refrence error: moment is not defined. I have already declare moment at the top of my file.

How can I able to use moment into $function mongoose aggregation query.

Comment: In [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/), it is explicitly mentioned that `$function` may decrease performance. If you are simply converting dates, consider using `$convert` or `$toDate` or `$dateFromString`

Comment: Short answer:  You can't.  `"$function"`'s `"body"` is sent to the MongoDB server and it is executed there.  You don't have any ability to `import` there.